# Get last 9 char of string

Tags: c++

Hello need help by getting a last N characters of a string : 
have a line like this :

```
PutPixel(x + N, y + N, 0, 0, 0); // N = 1 - 1000
```

and want to get last 9 symbols witch is "0, 0, 0);" , i have like 50k lines of those and each line have different numbers i want to find every line with 0,0,0); at the end and delete it from array , first i have to find them 
i have tried `line[N].substr(0,-9);` but that's did not work , i also tried `line[N].find("0, 0, 0);");` but this just game me long number liek "4294967295"

full code :

```
const string file = "putpixel.txt";
const int maxlines = 60000;
int main()
{
    string lines[maxlines];
    fileRead(file,lines);
    deleteBlack(lines);
    cout << lines[0].find("0, 0, 0);");
    return 0;
}

void fileRead(const string fn,string line[]){
    int index = 0;
    ifstream fin(fn.c_str());
    while(!fin.eof()){
        getline(fin,line[index],';');
        index++;
    }
    fin.close();
}
```

Comment: Is the comment actually part of the string? And the solution needs to be intelligent enough to ignore it?

Comment: What's the problem to calculate the position from **end** - 9 and use `substr()`?

Comment: @yahoo5000  Show the definition of the string and how it is initialized.

Comment: i update check out , and comments are not part of a string

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ i have tried that "substr(0,-9);" but its returns me whole line

Comment: @yahoo5000 I've seen that of course, but `0` is the start position, not end. There's even example for what you need in the [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr).

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  do you mean something like this ? substr(-9,lines[0].length());

Comment: @yahoo5000 No I meant this: `a.substr(a.size()-9);`

Comment: One problem I see with your code is that if you read only to `;` then you leave the comment in the file.  That comment will then mess up the next read.  You need top read in the full line and the do the string processing yourself or use something like `regex_replace`.

Comment: nah that comment is not in the file , i just add here just to show that length of the line is based on N , the file i read from is pure lines without a comment

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ post and answer , or should i post my self ?

Comment: @yahoo5000 Do you actually think such trivia is worrth to stay here?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  i am not sure but that's helped me

Comment: @yahoo5000 I leave it up to you to write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This code loads text from a file and searches for

`" 0, 0, 0"` and replaces it with a `" "` using

`searchresult = stringFile.find(" 0, 0, 0")` and

```
substr( searchresult + search_string.length() , stringFile.length() )
```

It will keep doing this until `searchresult = -1`. when it is,  it writes the  changed results back to the file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;


int main(){

    int searchresult=1;
    ifstream inFile;

    // load file into string
    inFile.open("putpixel.txt"); 
    stringstream strStream;
    strStream << inFile.rdbuf(); 
    string stringFile = strStream.str(); 
    inFile.close();

    cout<<"\nBefore replace \n";
    cout<<""<<stringFile<<" \n";


    // initialize search string and replace string
    string search_string = " 0, 0, 0";
    string replace_string = " ";


    // while searchresult is still greater than zero then keep searching
    while ( searchresult > 0 ){

        searchresult = stringFile.find(search_string);

        // if searchresult is greater than zero then keep doing this
        if(searchresult >= 0){
             string tmpstring = stringFile.substr(0,searchresult);
             tmpstring += replace_string;
             tmpstring += stringFile.substr(searchresult+search_string.length(), stringFile.length());
             stringFile = tmpstring;
        }

    }
    // update file after removing
    ofstream outFile("putpixel.txt");
    outFile << stringFile;
    outFile.close();

    cout<<"\nAfter replace \n";
    cout<<""<<stringFile<<" \n";

cout<<"\nPress ANY key to close.\n\n";
cin.ignore(); cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Output of `putpixel.txt` before :

```
PutPixel(x + N, y + N, 0, 0, 0);
PutPixel(x + N, y + N, 0, 0, 0);
PutPixel(x + N, y + N, 0, 0, 0);
PutPixel(x + N, y + N, 0, 0, 0);
```

Output of `putpixel.txt`  after:

```
PutPixel(x + N, y + N, );
PutPixel(x + N, y + N, );
PutPixel(x + N, y + N, );
PutPixel(x + N, y + N, );
```

Comment: i found better solution , read file -> check if condition true -> store into vector- > write file . but still tnx